# Prove a limit with condition specified at infinity

Tags: limits, dynamical-systems

Suppose that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\left(\dot{x}(t)+\gamma x(t)\right)=0,\quad \gamma>0.
$$
How can I prove
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}x(t)=0~?
$$
Please give a strict proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ley $z(t)=\dot x(t)+\gamma x(t)$, then $(x(t)\mathrm e^{\gamma t})'=z(t)\mathrm e^{\gamma t}$ hence $$x(t)=\mathrm e^{-\gamma t}x(0)+\mathrm e^{-\gamma t}\int_0^tz(s)\mathrm e^{\gamma s}\mathrm ds.$$ Now, using the hypothesis that $\gamma\gt0$, a direct epsilon-delta proof (or, in this case, an epsilon-$t_0$ proof...) shows that if $z(t)\to0$ when $t\to\infty$ then $x(t)\to0$ when $t\to\infty$.

So, let $\varepsilon$ be positive, there exists $t_0$ finite such that $|z(t)|\leqslant\varepsilon$ for every $t\geqslant t_0$ hence $|x(t)|\leqslant\ldots$

Comment: Thank you! Now I figure out that $|x(t)|\leq\alpha(t)+\varepsilon/\gamma$, where $\lim_{t\rightarrow}\alpha(t)=0$. Could you show me how I should make the final step?

Comment: This upper bound is valid for every $\varepsilon\gt0$ hence...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $y(t) = e^{\gamma t} x(t)$.  Then $\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-\gamma t} \dot{y}(t) = 0$.  If $-\epsilon < e^{-\gamma t} \dot{y}(t) < \epsilon$ for $t > T$, what can you say about $y$?